# How to know pig mode in grunt shell?

Tags: gruntjs, apache-pig

Could you please let me know "how to know pig mode (local or HDFS) in grunt shell"?

e.g.

1. > $ pig

   will move to grunt shell
2. > $ pig -x local

will also move to grunt shell

How can we determine whether we followed first path or second path for coming into grunt shell?

Answer (score 0):

Try using "ls".  If you get a normal directory listing, you are in local, if you get an HDFS directory listing, then you are not local, but using HDFS.

local :

```
grunt> ls
file:/home/cloudera/Documents   <dir>
```

HDFS :

```
grunt> ls
hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/.Trash    <dir>
```